# Kendo Grid Destroy Command sending entire HTML page to schema response -- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'results' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, crud

I am trying to add a Delete button to each row in my kendo grid. I added the destroy command to the grid configuration and have the Delete button showing, but when I click it, I receive a console error -- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'results' of undefined. This is referring to a line in the schema.parse that reads:

for (var i = 0, il = response.d.results.length; i < il; i++)

It's saying response is undefined. when I console.log(response) and it turns out that the entire html page is being sent in the response.

This doesn't make sense to me, because when I console.log(options) in transport.destroy and console.log(data) in the parameterMap, both console.logs show me in JSON format the row that needs to be deleted and includes the ID.

So why is it being transported to the schema as the entire html page? console.log(response) in the schema starts with <DOCTYPE !HTML> etc. and includes the whole page. Can anyone tell me why this is?

and yes, I have already included editable: "inline" in the grid configuration. Thanks

````
var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: function () {
                    ***omitted for privacy, but read works. the grid loads fine***
                },
                cache: false,
                type: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json; odata=verbose'
                }
            },
            destroy: {
                url: function (options) {
                    console.log(options);
                    console.log("destroy command called");
                }
            },
            parameterMap: function (data, type) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log(type);
                if (type == "destroy") {
                    // send the destroyed data items as the "models" service parameter encoded in JSON
                    return { models: kendo.stringify(data.models) }
                }
            }
        },
        pageSize: 10,
        sort: {
            field: "Modified",
            dir: "desc"
        },
        filter: {
            logic: 'and',
            filters: [{
                field: 'State',
                operator: 'eq',
                value: 'Submitted'
            }]
        },
        error: function (e) {
            kendo.alert(e.errors);
        },
        schema: {
            errors: "error",
            parse: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                var data = [];
                for (var i = 0, il = response.d.results.length; i < il; i++) {
                    var item = response.d.results[i];
                    //Create new fields to handle filtering by Date (instead of DateTime)
                    item.ModifiedFilter = new Date(new Date(item.Modified).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0));
                    item.CreatedFilter = new Date(new Date(item.Created).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0));
                    data.push(item);
                }
                return data;
            },
            total: function (response) {
                return response.length;
            },
            model: {
                id: 'Id',
                fields: {
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

The [dataSource.destroy.url](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/transport.destroy#transportdestroyurl) handler should return the url which the grid will request for the destroy operation. As in your case the destroy.url handler does not return anything, the "" url is requested, which is equivalent to requesting your landing page, thus, HTML is returned.

If you do not intend to update the server on delete and just visually remove the row, simply define the destroy as a handler which does nothing.

e.g.

```
    destroy: function (options) {
            options.success(options.data.models);
    }
```

Comment: when you say visually remove the row, does that mean the row will still be gone on page refresh? That is my goal. When I add your snippet of code, it says "Cannot read property 'models' of undefined." If I make it options.success(options), it says "options.success is not a function"

Comment: also, my transport.read is currently configured as an object. so I can't configure transport.destroy as a function because they must be consistent according to Kendo

Comment: If you want to reflect the change on the server, then you have to send a request to an end point which will update the database. For example in their [demo](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-inline), note that transport.destroy is an object which contains a URL, this url is requested upon delete. I'd suggest you to examine the network tab of your devtools to get a better idea of what the grid sends to the server and what the expected response is.

Comment: I'm even trying this solution here and the entire html page is still being sent in the response: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/remove

I don't understand. I already have the grid row Id with options.Id. Still, the entire html page is being sent in the response. How can I tell the destroy command to simply use the id of the grid row to delete the grid row?